# Google Kubernetes Engine - 'kubens' command not found error

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-organizing-with-namespaces) blog, the `kubens` command is used to show all the available namespaces in **GCP's** GKE, but when I tried using this command, and after connecting to the cluster it says:

> command not found

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: In the guide they explain that you need to download the tool. It is a local binary that is used to simplify dealing with namespaces in Kubernetes. It is not part of GKE (same as kubectl isn't something that is part of GKE, it is a binary on your local system).

Answer (score 2):

First you have to install `kubens` in your machine. Go through the below link for installation.

https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx